# Sogou Pinyin typing blank

Tags: input-method

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 in the company. we have a few computer that needs to be in Chinese input method and they prefer sogou pinyin. lately, i am having issues as the image below. can someone help me as i have search the website and did not find any solution

Sogou typing blank

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? 2.2.0.0100 has been released recently, can you try that?